# ¿Cúal es el formato correcto de line_format en Reader dentro de la liberia Surpise?

Tags: python, jupyter, importación, read

Estoy usando la librería `surprise` para poder hacer un sistema de recomendación, lo que me lleva a importar unas tablas y usar el `reader` para poderlas ingresar, de momento mi código tiene esta estructura:

```
reader= Reader(line_format = 'id data release video IMb 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19', sep= '|')
```

la tabla que estoy tratando de importar tiene esta estructura, y solo después de que el formato del `reader` sea correcto procederé a importarla:

```
1|pelicula|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)|0|0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

Por lo que no logro entender donde esta el error si parece que sigue la estructura de las columnas y el separador.

He probado algunas combinaciones diferentes de poner menos columnas, separar por `|` cada nombre dentro del código pero no tiene efecto, la documentación de `surprise` es limitada así que no estoy muy segura que esta fallando:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-12-0d721674d219> in <module>
> ----> 1 reader= Reader(line_format = 'id data release video IMb 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19', sep= '|')
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\surprise\reader.py in __init__(self, name, line_format, sep, rating_scale, skip_lines)
>      69             # check that all fields are correct
>      70             if any(field not in entities for field in splitted_format):
> ---> 71                 raise ValueError('line_format parameter is incorrect.')
>      72 
>      73             self.indexes = [splitted_format.index(entity) for entity in
>
> ValueError: line_format parameter is incorrect.
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tus datos no son apropiados para usarlos en Surprise directamente, deben ser "cocinados" antes. `Reader` y por tanto los datasets esperan el siguiente formato:

```
user ; item ; rating ; [timestamp]
```

dónde el `timestamp` es opcional y el orden de las columnas puede cambiar. Esto es precisamente lo que permite especificar `line_format`, no sirve para especificar el número de columnas y el nombre de tu tabla.  Serían formatos válidos cualquier combinación posible de lo anterior:

```
user item rating
user rating item
item user rating
item rating user
rating user item
rating item user
user item timestamp rating
user rating item timestamp
user rating timestamp item
user timestamp item rating
user timestamp rating item
item user rating timestamp
item user timestamp rating
item rating user timestamp
item rating timestamp user
item timestamp user rating
item timestamp rating user
rating user item timestamp
rating user timestamp item
rating item user timestamp
rating item timestamp user
rating timestamp user item
rating timestamp item user
timestamp user item rating
timestamp user rating item
timestamp item user rating
timestamp item rating user
timestamp rating user item
timestamp rating item user
```

Por lo tanto, carga tu csv (o cualquier origen de tu tabla o tablas de datos) usando Pandas (como `pandas.read_csv`), trabaja con tu tabla o tablas hasta conseguir un DataFrame con la estructura descrita (`usuario item calificación`) y luego usa [`surprise.dataset.Dataset.load_from_df`](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataset.html#surprise.dataset.Dataset.load_from_df) para cargar el dataset y poder usar surprise (validación cruzada, entrenamiento, predicción, ...).